# The most effective way of computing distance to sphere in CUDA?

Tags: math, optimization, cuda, render

I'm raymarching Signed Distance Fields in CUDA and the scene I'm rendering contains thousands of spheres (spheres have their location stored in device buffer, so my SDF function iterates through *all* of the spheres for each pixel).

Currently, I'm computing distance to sphere surface as:

`sqrtf( dot( pos - sphere_center, pos - sphere_center ) ) - sphere_radius`

With the `sqrt()` function, the rendering took about 250ms for my scene. However, when I removed the call to `sqrt()` and left just `dot( pos - sphere_center, pos - sphere_center ) - sphere_radius`, the rendering time dropped to 17ms (and rendering black image).

The `sqrt()` function seems to be the bottleneck so I want to ask if there is a way I can improve my rendering time (either by using different formula that does not use square root or different rendering approach)?

I'm already using `-use-fast-math`.

**Edit:** I've tried formula suggested by [Nico Schertler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210053/nico-schertler), but it didn't work in my renderer. [Link to M(n)WE on Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tlf3zB).

Comment: If you only need the zero levelset, you can use the field `dot( pos - sphere_center, pos - sphere_center ) - sphere_radius * sphere_radius`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I have tried that formula before, but it didn't work with my current rendering approach. Here is [link to Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tlf3zB) with both formulas (set `USE_SQRT` to `0` for sqrt-less formula).

Comment: @wlcezar `currPt += rd * currDst;` is obviously not going to work if `currDst` is not an actual distance…but even when it is, this probably doesn't do what you want…unless your ray hits the center of the sphere exactly, the distance you move along the ray here is not a distance measured along the ray…

Comment: And just in case: If all you want is to intersect spheres, then there is no need to use distance fields. The intersection of a sphere and a ray can simply be computed directly…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel thank you, unfortunately, (I think) I need to use ray marching, because the scene I'm rendering contains also other SDF functions. My final SDF function looks like this: `min(distance_to_the_closest_sphere, distance_to_the_closest_object_in_the_rest_of_the_scene)`.

Comment: @wclezar that's fine, in this case, however, you will generally not be able to just directly skip all the way to the point where you hit an object and will have to properly step through the distance field anyways…

Comment: Maybe you can "propagate" the use of the squared distance to the rest of your computation. At the very least you could do: `min(squared_distance_to_closest_sphere, distance_to_the_closest_object_in_the_rest_of_the_scene^2)` - right?

Comment: `--use-fast-math` has [no effect](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#intrinsic-functions) on `sqrt()` AFAIK.  If you are using `sqrt()` (i.e. not `sqrtf()`)  you may get some benefit if you can switch to e.g. [`__fsqrt_rn()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SINGLE_1gf021e85b5e9de141a0fc2ff6fbe85875)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I implemented the approach suggested by @einpoklum and it did bring significant improvement!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Making my comment into an answer since it seems to have worked for OP)

You're feeling the pain of having to compute `sqrt()`. I sympathize... It would be great if you could just, umm, *not* do that. Well, what's stopping you? After all, the square-distance to a sphere is a monotone function from $R^+$ to $R^+$ - hell, it's actually a convex bijection! The problem is that you have non-squared distances coming from elsewhere, and you compute:

```
min(sqrt(square_distance_to_the_closest_sphere), 
    distance_to_the_closest_object_in_the_rest_of_the_scene)
```

So let's just do things the other way around: Instead of taking the square-root of the squared distance to the sphere, let's square the *other* distance:

```
min(square_distance_to_the_closest_sphere,
    distance_to_the_closest_object_in_the_rest_of_the_scene^2)
```

This makes the same choice as the un-squared `min()` computation, due to the monotonicity of the squaring function. From here, try to propagate the use of the squared distance further in your program, avoiding taking a root as far as possible, perhaps even all the way.